# How to avoid getting matched by FROM_DAEMON on promail?

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server, procmail

An admin of a service, which is primarily email based, complained that mails from my self-hosted email server gets matched by FROM_DAEMON on their procmail setup which ends up throwing away my emails.

Here's the exact message from the admin:

> You're sending mail from mail@mydomain.tld, which matches FROM_DAEMON; we
>   block that because of mail loops.

Relevant portion of their server's logs:

> 2016-10-21 11:24:57 1bxXwX-0008Oa-CI <= `mail@mydomain.tld H=mydomain.tld
>   [ip.of.my.mailserver]` P=esmtp S=1450 id=03668fb3-cc12-b128-e583-402cb452a525@mydomain.tld
>   2016-10-21 11:24:57 1bxXwX-0008Oa-CI => |/org/bugs.debian.org/mail/run-procmail  `R=virt_direct T=address_pipe` QT=0s DT=0s
>   2016-10-21 11:24:57 1bxXwX-0008Oa-CI Completed

My setup:
Debian 8.6, Postfix, procmail, Dovecot. No clamav, No SpamAssassin.

What changes should I make in my configuration that would keep me away from the FROM_DAEMON filter?

Comment: Although I feel the recipient should probably simply whitelist your messages rather than asking you to work around their mail filter.  You should take a look at the headers of an actual email message, but I think they're simply recommending that you set a different sender address in your mail scripts, something different from `mail@example.com` (and probably also not `daemon` ,  `postmaster`  or similar either)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see any other solution than changing the `mail@` on your side to an identifier which does not get filtered on their side.

Based on the log excerpt, I'm guessing the organization you are corresponding with is Debian, and that it's completely out of the question that they would add a special case just for you in ther system.

Not being able to send bug reports from `mail@example.tld` when you could just as well use, say, `debbugs@example.tld` seems like a minor inconvenience.

You could configure an alias on your side to route replies back to your preferred address, and perhaps even correspondingly rewrite outgoing email from this address to this particular destination, though that seems like a lot of work for very marginal gains.